# add settings in Android builtin Settings

Tags: android, settings, application-settings

I want to add an item in android builtin settings, for my application.

Can any body guide me through any tutorial or code that how can i acheive this?

Thanks a bunch in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something tells me this is not what you want... I don't know how to achieve it but I have a feeling if it is even possible, it wouldn't work on all devices. I'd stick to an in app settings menu like everything else. At least that way you know it's possible and will work on all devices.